# Add CMS block as custom tab in product view page Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-view, tabs

I'd like to add a static block as an additional custom tab in Magento 2.

**CMS Static Block (hello-world)**

```
<p>Hello world!</p>
```

**catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.helloworld" template="product/view/hello-world.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
 <arguments>
  <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Hello World</argument>
  <argument name="priority" xsi:type="string">4</argument>
 </arguments>
</block>
```

**hello-world.phtml**

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('hello-world')->toHtml();?>
```

At the moment nothing is being displayed. Can anyone suggest an edit to get the code above working?

Comment: what is your static block id?

Comment: It is 'hello-world' and I've updated the above, as such.

Comment: your phtml file is call in tab?

Comment: That's what I am trying to achieve but at the moment with the code above, the tab doesn't appear...

Comment: Have you check with static text in your phtml file and its called or not?

Comment: Yes tried that, and no, not called unfortunately. I wondered if it's anything to do with the 'block class' declaration?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59545/discussion-between-yorkiemagento-and-rakesh-jesadiya).

Comment: Really surprised there's not a straightforward way to get this working.

Comment: @YorkieMagento Did you get my answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add **Vendor_Module** before template path

Try this, **catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
          <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.helloworld" template="Vendor_Module::product/view/hello-world.phtml" group="detailed_info">
             <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Hello World</argument>
             </arguments>
          </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your **catalog_product_view.xml** by

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.helloworld" template="Vendor_Module::product/view/hello-world.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Hello World</argument>
                    <argument name="priority" xsi:type="string">4</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Your template attribute should be **Vendor_Module::product/view/hello-world.phtml**

**Flush cache** OR delete **var/cache/ and var/page_cache/**

Answer (score 2):

You can reference the static block directly within xml and avoid having to use the phtml file using below. This is tested and working on my store:

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="product.helloworld.tab" as="helloworld.tab" group="detailed_info" >
            <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Hello World</argument>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">hello-world</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
      </referenceBlock>
    </body>
 </page>
```

Above XML should go in your theme within:

```
'Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml'
```

Or if within a module:

```
'view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml'
```

Then make sure cache is flushed.

```
bin/magento cache:clean layout
```

I normally use the below however to reference a static block within phtml if you need to continue using the template method maybe try this within the template phtml file:

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('hello-world')->toHtml();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the reference to the product tabs container block, try the below:

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.helloworld" template="product/view/hello-world.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
 <arguments>
  <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Hello World</argument>
  <argument name="priority" xsi:type="string">4</argument>
 </arguments>
</block>
</referenceBlock>
 </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Sadly not Baber, the block is already placed within that container.

Comment: :(, I would have a look at this guide it helped me create the custom tabs I needed - https://blog.landofcoder.com/add-custom-tab-product-page-magento2